# filter array of json in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

How can i filter an array of json in swift having only certain key value pairs?

**my array looks like:**

```
[{
  "status" : "true",
  "score" : "3",
  "correct" : "3",
  "chapter" : "34",
  "answer" : "342432",
  "solutionText" : "abcd",
}, {

  "status" : "true",
  "score" : "0",
  "correct" : "2",
  "chapter" : "35",
  "answer" : "35854",
  "solutionText" : "abc",

}]
```

i want to get an array of json output having only `status`, `chapter` & `correct` key value pairs.

Like:

```
[{
  "status" : "true",
  "correct" : "3",
  "chapter" : "34",
}, {

  "status" : "true",
  "correct" : "2",
  "chapter" : "35",
}]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you already did?

Comment: Use `Decodable` and declare the struct just with the required keys/members. Pretty easy.

Comment: Hey if you want something that let you crate structrue or class for JSON. Please try this out https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: @TheiOSDev decent tool but i think he needs to understand the codables protocols first so he can handle this by his own in the future, then he can jump into tools that helps him do that faster, any other link related to the codables i think would help him better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this is your `JSON`

```
var myJSON = """
[{
    "status" : "true",
    "score" : "3",
    "correct" : "3",
    "chapter" : "34",
    "answer" : "342432",
    "solutionText" : "abcd"
    }, {

        "status" : "true",
        "score" : "0",
        "correct" : "2",
        "chapter" : "35",
        "answer" : "35854",
        "solutionText" : "abc"

    }]
"""
```

Simply create a `Decodable` `struct` like this

```
typealias  MyArray = [MyObject] // Use this to decode 

struct MyObject: Codable {
    let status, correct, chapter: String
}
```

And use it like this

```
//Usage
var myJSONData = myJSON.data(using: .utf8)! // converting the JSON to data 
let objArray = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyArray.self, from: myJSONData) // decoding the json data into an object


   //how to access
print(objArray.count)// number of elements in my array
print(objArray.first!) // getting the first object
 let myObject =  obj[0] // also getting the first object by index
 myObject.chapter
 myObject.correct
 myObject.status
```

Read about `Codable`  [here](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999) .

Comment: Doesn't your answer look the same as what already been added  ? , plus you don't clarity the error you discussing

Comment: @Sh_Khan Read about `Codable` here,  section i believe he can get every explanation possible for each step, + already answered question on SO and i didn't copy pasted your answer if thats what you referring to, i can't tell who posted it first, but if u want i can remove it if it gives you any problems at all

Comment: @Sh_Khan and if it was a rare case we would for sure all of us as a community work around it and try to get explanations etc, but its straight forward case that has been posted way too many times,  idk even why this question is still not closed, kinda weird no mods online or smth

Comment: @MohmmadS my output looks like ```[quizApp.SessionReport.MyObject(status: "true", correct: "1", chapter: "35")]``` how to get only array of JSON?

Comment: its that array but it prints out the objects like this ^_^  try those commands out , you will get the idea `print(obj.count)// 2
print(obj.first!)`

Comment: each object contains the elements you need, so the first index lets say 0 contains an object you can access that object properties simply `let myObject =  obj[0] // getting the first object
 myObject.chapter
 myObject.correct
 myObject.status `

Answer (score 0):

If it's already in an object, you can try

```
filteredArray = myArray.map { ["status": $0.status, "correct": $0.correct, "chapter": $0.chapter]  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
do {
    
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from:data)
 
}
catch {
    
    print(error)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
  let status, correct, chapter: String
}
```

Correct json

```
[{
    "status" : "true",
    "score" : "3",
    "correct" : "3",
    "chapter" : "34",
    "answer" : "342432",
    "solutionText" : "abcd"
    }, {
        
        "status" : "true",
        "score" : "0",
        "correct" : "2",
        "chapter" : "35",
        "answer" : "35854",
        "solutionText" : "abc"
        
}]
```

It's more suitable to make

> status a bool not string
>
> correct & chapter to be integers

so json look like

```
[{
    "status" : true,
    "score" : "3",
    "correct" : 3,
    "chapter" : 34,
    "answer" : "342432",
    "solutionText" : "abcd"
    }, {
        
        "status" : true,
        "score" : "0",
        "correct" : 2,
        "chapter" : 35,
        "answer" : "35854",
        "solutionText" : "abc"
        
}]
```

you can also make other values like that if you need , then your model will look like

```
struct Root: Codable {
  let status: Bool
  let correct, chapter: Int
}
```

**Edit:**

```
let data = try content.rawData() // this inside do block
```

where `content` is of type `JSON`

Comment: whats the purpose of `do catch` ?

Comment: it's useful when you have decoding errors like for example adding a non optional key that doesn't exist in the json or exists but with a different type or mistyping the correct key name , it'll help tracking the problem to fix it

Comment: true, ofc but i mean in this case its not like that critical pretty simple straight forward .. `?` would be just fine probably i think

Comment: it's a best practice for advising beginners even if 100% sure  will not throw any errors

Comment: @Sh_Khan getting this error Cannot convert value of type '[JSON]' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: also good point, but sometimes too many info could let them believe that the community will always resolve their issues  and teach them .. idk fro my pov id rather to give them a link to the subject to read more about whats going on they would probably understand more better and reduces the chances of such questions  in the future , for example you didn't explain in the answer for the op why you are handling errors , he might just end up copy paste it and using it like that for the rest of his life xd

Comment: @AMANSHARMA You need to convert it to data first, check out other answers you got 4

Comment: @AMANSHARMA it seems you use swiftyJson so look to my edited answer

Answer (score -1):

try `Decodable` of swift

```
class MyObjectsClass : Decodable {
   var objects : [Objects]?
}

class Objects : Decodable {
   var status : String?
   var correct : String?
   var chapter : String?
}
```

While Decoding

```
let decodedValue = try? JSONDecoder.decode(MyObjectsClass.self, from : data)
// where data from API calls
```

Comment: This won't work and why a class and why are all properties optional?

Comment: Because the root object of the JSON is not a dictionary.

Comment: This is not a dictionary and I haven't declared a dictionary.

Comment: You do have declared the representation of a dictionary with a key `objects` which doesn't exist.